# anime lines material

Tags: materials, shaders

I'm trying to get that green-yellow lines coming from back to my scene which is inspired by this
[image]

I can create that lines on plane surface but unable to find do it with circular way or in a cone object

Comment: Hello, is it supposed to be animated? Do you care if it's projected onto a cone or you prefer a plane?

Comment: I'm rendering a still image for now so no need to animated (but it would be great if u know) , no I don't care about plane or cone because I'm looking for just final render , I saw it in cone view that's why I try with cone @moonboots

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could stretch a *Noise Texture* onto a cylinder, and mix it with a gradient so that it becomes completely white:

[image]

Comment: Thank u so much it solved my problem , additionally I need to change x value in scale to 0 to get same result as yours  @moonboots